# Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'comments' cannot be null

Tags: php, pdo

I have already tried checking for related post but it doesn't seem to help me fix my problem at hand. I am trying to create an page for appointments where data are saved in the database. however, these two error message kept appearing on my window:

> Notice: Undefined index: comments in C:\xampp\htdocs\db\connect2.php
>   on line 29 Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:
>   1048 Column 'comments' cannot be null

here is the code
**php**

```
<form name="appointments" action="" method="POST">
<label>Name (First/Last)</label> <br>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="required" placeholder="Please Enter Name"> <br>
<label>Email Address</label> <br>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" required="required" placeholder="youremail@yahoo.com"> <br>
<label>Phone Number</label> <br>
<input type="text" name="contactno" id="contactno" required="required" placeholder="9221234567"> <br>
<label>Nature of Appointment</label> <br>
<select name="service" id="service">
<option value="other">Other</option>
<option value="consultation">Consultation</option>
<option value="Surgery">Surgery</option>
</select> <br>
</div>
<label>Preferred Appointment Date</label> <br>
<input type="date" name="prefDate" id="prefDate"> <br>
<label>Comments</label> <br>
<textarea rows="12" cols="40" name="comments" form="usrform" placeholder="Your comments here..."></textarea> <br>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="btnRegister" name = "schedule" value="Send Your Request">
</form>
```

Here is my **connect2.php**

```
<?php
    //Local Server Information
    $server = "127.0.0.1";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $db = "myDB";

    $name = "";
    $email = "";
    $contactno = "";
    $service = "";
    $prefDate = "";
    if (isset($_POST['comments']) && !empty($_POST['comments'])) {
        $comments = $_POST['comments'];
    } else {
        $comments = "";
    }
    //Check if connection was successful
    try {
        $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$db","$username","$password");
        $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        if(isset($_POST['schedule']) )
        {
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $contactno = $_POST['contactno'];
            $service = $_POST['service'];
            $prefDate = $_POST['prefDate'];
            $comments = $_POST['comments'];


            $insert = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO appointments(name, email,contactno, service, prefDate, comments) values(:name, :email, :contactno, :service, :prefDate, :comments)");

            $insert->bindParam(':name', $name);
            $insert->bindParam(':email', $email);
            $insert->bindParam(':contactno', $contactno);
            $insert->bindParam(':service', $service);
            $insert->bindParam(':prefDate', $prefDate);
            $insert->bindParam(':comments', $comments);

            $insert->execute();
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        //die("Oops! Something went wrong with your database.");
        echo "Error: ". $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

This is the line where the error says the problem was.

> $comments = $_POST['comments'];

I already tried hard coding it like $comments="you comment";
It went through with no errors and the data appears on the database. However, when I use the code above, error appears. Anyone help me please. Did i miss something? NOt sure what went wrong since the other line seems to work.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So tried to fix it applying your suggestions. and it seems the one responsible for the error in this portion of the code I entered under php.

```
<textarea rows="12" cols="40" name="comments" form="usrform" placeholder="Your comments here..."></textarea>
```

is

> form="usrform"

removing it simply made the code to work. it seems that the form stops in the prefDate because i assigned a different form name by accident on the textarea tag.

thanks the two who gave advise that made me see what went wrong

Answer (score 4):

the error message tells itself - you are trying to not assign value in column which cannot be empty. solution is - in your database table, set default value as null to your `comments` field. if you use phpmyadmin
[image: printscreen]

or you can run `mysql` query (or other database, which you use), something like this

```
ALTER TABLE <table name> MODIFY COLUMN comments <column type> DEFAULT NULL;
```

Comment: I tried doing this, the said error disappeared. however, the data now appears at the database aside from comments which appears as null. T^T

Comment: that how it should work. if dont you have default value (in your case null) and you dont assign anything - filed will have null value. if you want empty string `''` you can run `ALTER TABLE <talbe name> MODIFY COLUMN comments <type> NOT NULL DEFAULT '';`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$comments = !empty($_POST['comments']) ? $_POST['comments'] : 'Default Comment';
```

Comment: Hi I tried doing this, the Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'comments' cannot be null

error disappeared and it proceeded with no error at all. however, the comment only inserts 'default comment' and not what i typed in