# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 laravel Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I now have 3 tables
[image]
In my table **cars**, I have get my 2 foreign key of the table **series** and **marks**.

My goal in fact, is to create a recording.

[image]

I have a error message...

**SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Le champ 'name' ne peut être vide (null) (SQL: insert into `series` (`name`, `fk_mark`)**

[image]
[image]

My problem is in my **SerieController** ?

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Serie;
use App\Mark;


class SerieController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $series = Serie::oldest()->paginate(5);
        return view('admin.series.index', compact('series'))
                  ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1)-1)*5);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $marks = Mark::all();
        return view('admin.series.create', compact('marks'));

    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        Serie::create([
            'name' => request('name'),
            'fk_mark' => request('fk_mark')
        ]);


        return redirect()->route('series.index')
                    ->with('success', 'save');

     }
```

I think my problem is in my **CarController**, my syntax is correct ?

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Car; 
use App\Serie;
use App\Mark;

class CarController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $cars = Car::oldest()->paginate(5);
        return view('admin.cars.index', compact('cars'))
                  ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1)-1)*5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {

        $series = Serie::all();
        $marks = Mark::all();
        return view('admin.cars.create', compact('series' , 'marks'));


    }


    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        Car::create([
            'matriculation' => request('matriculation'),
            'fk_serie' => request('fk_serie'),
            'fk_mark' => request('fk_mark')
        ]);


        return redirect()->route('cars.index')
                    ->with('success', 'save');

     }
```

Thank you for your help, I am really stuck.

Edit: Here is my tables on PhpMyAdmin

Table **cars**

[image]

Table **series**

[image]

Table **marks**

[image]

Comment: You're passing in an empty `name`, which is set to NOT NULL in your database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: SQLSTATE\[23000\]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'comments' cannot be null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46399519/error-sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-1048-column-comments-c)

Comment: @aynber: I have edited my first message, is it my database seems to be good? Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should validate your requests. In your case, it is possible that name property from request is null.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. it's on my phpmyadmin?I have edited my first message with my fields. Is it correct please? Thanks

Comment: You should validate your data in application. You can read about it here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation. In example: before calling create method, make sure that you check the request data. `$request->validate(['name' => 'required|string'])`

Comment: @ Harven: Thank you Harven