# How to fix error > Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'status' cannot be null

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I'm trying to edit the status field in the orders table. And I get such an error:SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'status' cannot be null (SQL: update `feedbacks` set `status` = ?, `feedbacks`.`updated_at` = 2021-02-24 11:24:35 where `id` = 3)"

My edit_feedback.blade.php :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit_feedback" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Formular de editare a unui feedback</h5>

                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">


                <form  id="feedback_form" method="GET" >
                  {{ csrf_field() }}
                
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <input type="hidden" name="feedback_id" id="feedback_id">


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>
                                Status
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" name="feedback_status" id="feedback_status" class="form-control" placeholder="public/private" required>

                        </div>

                    </div>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Renunță</button>
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Editează</button>
            </div>

            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

My route :

```
Route::get('/feedback/{id}/edit','App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@feedback_edit');
```

My controller :

```
 public function feedback_edit(Request $request, $id)
    {
       
        $feedbacks = Feedbacks::find($id);
        $feedbacks->status = $request->input('feedback_status');
        $feedbacks->save();
        return response()->json(['status' => 1, 'msg' => 'Feedback-ul a fost editat cu succes']);
    }
```

My jQuery/ajax :

```
$('#feedback_form').on('submit',function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            method: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: '/feedback/'+$('#feedback_id').val()+'/edit',
            data: new FormData(this),
            processData: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            complete: function(r) {
                var data = r.responseJSON;
                if (data.status == 0) {
                    console.log('error');
                } else {
                    $('#feedback_form')[0].reset();
                    $('#edit_feedback').modal('hide');
                    //  location.reload();
                    // alert(data.msg);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Does this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46399519/error-sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-1048-column-comments-c)  solve your problem ?

Comment: What is the output of `$request->all();`?

Comment: only empty [ ].

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$request->input('feedback_status')` with something that actually delivers a value.

eg. try `$data = request()->all();` to see what is even there.

Comment: Replace `$(this).attr('method')` with `"POST"`. That JS also doesn't consider a CFR token.

Comment: The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

Comment: I also tried with GET, but I have the same error : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'status' cannot be null (SQL: update `feedbacks` set `status` = ?, `feedbacks`.`updated_at` = 2021-02-24 11:53:06 where `id` = 3)"